# RxJS 6: migrate fromPromise to from with TypescriptTypings

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

How do I migrate from RxJS 5 to RxJS 6 fromPromise while keeping typings in place?

RxJS 5, all ok:

```
return Observable.fromPromise<SomeInterface>(somePromiseFn())
```

RxJS 6:

```
return from<SomeInterface>(somePromiseFn())
```

complains:

```
Type 'SomeInterface' does not satisfy the constraint 'ObservableInput<any>'.
  Type 'SomeInterface' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<any>'.
```

So If I understand correctly it expects that from will have a sequence, array. But promises can return any objects?

Comment: What does `somePromiseFn()` return?

Comment: did you try `from<Promise<SomeInterface>>(...`

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is to use `ObservableInput<T>`. Like this:

```
return from<ObservableInput<SomeInterface>>(somePromiseFn())
```

This may sound a little weird because you're telling the `from` function, which interface `somePromiseFn` will return! What I recommend you to do instead is something like this:

```
// Declare somePromiseFn
function somePromiseFn(): Promise<SomeInterface> {}

// Now use it like this:
return from(somePromiseFn())
```

So now the `from` function knows the type of the Promise it's going to convert so it'll infer the generic.